# Why does (reduce * []) evaluate to 1?

Tags: clojure

In clojure, calling `reduce *` on en empty collection returns 1. This is quite surprising.

I made this discovery while creating a factorial function, defined as follow :

```
(defn factorial [n] (reduce * (take-while #(> % 0) (iterate dec n))))
```

`(factorial 0)` is correctly returning `1`, without me having to write a special case for zero.
How come ?

Comment: I just finished writing this question and it occured to me that it may be the identity element for the requested operation that is actually being returned (since `(reduce + '())` returns 0. Any further explanation appreciated.

Comment: The identity of multiplication is 1. http://www.mathwords.com/i/identity_of_an_operation.htm

Comment: @dsm That's pretty much what I said :)

Comment: Yeah, thought I'd link the further explanation you requested.

Comment: Wow, just realized I could have replaced the whole `(take-while #(> % 0) (iterate dec n))` by `(range 1 (inc n))`…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Checking the code for [`*`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L967) and [`+`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L943) shows that these two functions implement the 0-arity case by returning the identity for the operation. In the case of `*` the code is (with dosctring and metadata removed):

```
(defn *
  ([] 1)
  ([x] (cast Number x))
  ([x y] (. clojure.lang.Numbers (multiply x y)))
  ([x y & more]
     (reduce1 * (* x y) more)))
```

Comment: Thank you! It may be obvious, but I’m a Clojure newbie – I've read about runtime polymorphism, but I didn't know how it worked until now. I will use `source` more often in the future (just found out about it too) :)

Comment: The fact that Clojure is an open source language and a great part of it is implemented in Clojure itself is pretty awesome. :)

Comment: btw. the reason for (\*) yielding 1 is that (Z,*,1) form a Monoid. A couple of nice properties fall out of this fact. One can exploit it when parallelizing reduce.

Answer (score 0):

The main point here is the behaviour of `reduce`. In

```
(reduce f s)
```

... if `s` is empty, the call returns `(f)`.

Since `(*)` is `1`,

```
(reduce * ())
; 1
```

`reduce` doesn't care that `1` is the identity for `*`. Though `1` is also the right identity for `/`,

```
(reduce / ())
; ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: core$-SLASH- ...
```

... because, as it happens, `/` does not declare a `0` arity version.

Comment: Subtraction is neither associative nor commutative, hence there is no identity element `i` such that `x - i = i - x = x`.

Comment: @dsm "Let (S, ∗) be a set S with a binary operation ∗ on it. ... an element e of S is called a ... right identity if a ∗ e = a for all a in S" - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_identity). So, as I said, `0` *is* a right identity for `-`.

Comment: The right identity is a very specific subset, not a complete identity.

Comment: @dsm To remove any remaining ambiguity, I've removed the parentheses round *right* in *right identity*. By the way, the *conditions* on a right identity are a subset of those for an identity. Right identities themselves are a *superset* of identities, since every identity is a right identity, but not vice versa. I know what you meant, but it's not exactly what you wrote.

Comment: Should have chosen my words more carefully :)